# Adjust node configuration breaks sqlproxy and scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

Today I tried to change the node type of the cluster backing a cloud composer environment and switch to the Ubuntu image instead of COS. I did so by adding a second node pool to the GKE cluster, then deleting the first one and have all workloads migrated.

This spawns following errors in the airflow-sqlproxy logs:

```
couldn't connect to "XXXXX:europe-west1:XXXXX": ensure that the Cloud SQL API is enabled for your project (https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=sqladmin). Error during createEphemeral for XXXXX:europe-west1:XXXXX: googleapi: Error 403: Insufficient Permission, insufficientPermissions
```

The scheduler fails to start completely and emits following stacktraces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 826, in scheduler
    job.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 192, in run
    session.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 943, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 467, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 447, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2254, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2380, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2344, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 391, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 556, in execute
    uow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 156, in save_obj
    base_mapper, states, uowtransaction
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 286, in _organize_states_for_save(states):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1252, in _connections_for_states
    connection = uowtransaction.transaction.connection(base_mapper)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 294, in connection
    return self._connection_for_bind(bind, execution_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 398, in _connection_for_bind
    conn = self._parent._connection_for_bind(bind, execution_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 409, in _connection_for_bind
    conn = bind.contextual_connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2123, in contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2162, in _wrap_pool_connect
e, dialect, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1476, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2158, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 403, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 788, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 532, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1193, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1190, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 350, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 477, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 671, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 106, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 410, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0") (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

It seems that the connection to the backing SQL database is now broken. Its still the same cluster but the nodes are different. Are there any additional configurations I must update?

Answer (score 1):

The SQLProxy relies on the credentials of the service account used to create the Composer environment. If you do not change any settings, this should be the Compute engine default service account.

You should verify that the new node pool and your previous Composer node pool share the same service account.

Additionally, you should verify the new pool has sufficient scopes-- you are likely missing the sql admin scope. See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/node-pools/create?hl=en_US&_ga=2.222157720.-1458722175.1530287449